# How to pass a logged in value between classes?

Tags: php, class, authentication

I have a user class which has a structure like this

```
class User
{

    private $_data, $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //Initialising variables
    }

    public function login()
    {
        //logs in the user and assigns the value true to $_isLoggedIn i.e $this->_isLoggedIn = true
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }

}
```

What I want to be able to do is use the `isLoggedIn` value to check if a user is loggedIn inside another class to check if the user is logged in. So what I have done is like this

```
class Oranges
{
    public function write()
    {
        $user = new User;
        if($user->isLogedIn) echo 'Logged In';
    }
}
```

But every time I call the Oranges class I lose the value of `_isLoggedIn`.

**How can I be able to check if the user is logged in without using sessions which I am told are not secure.**

Comment: Declare `$user` as a class variable before doing `$this->user = new User;` so that login data is the same all the time

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. One solution would be storing the user object in a session var when it is instantiated which could be passed to the Oranges object as a parameter when it is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `write()` method, instantiated a `new User`, that is the incorrect point.

you can consider saving the `User` and then use the same object each time.

For example, save to a variable

```
class Oranges
{
    protected  $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new User; 
    }

    public function write()
    {
        if($this->user->isLogedIn) echo 'Logged In';
    }
}
```

**Or** you can consider using a [singleton](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)

```
class User
{

    //...

    private static $instance;

    //...

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new User();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

then you can call `User::getInstance()` in anywhere to get `User`

```
if (User::getInstance()->isLogedIn()) echo 'Logged In';
```